# Why seeds from the same citrus (kumquat) tree produce different sprouts?

Tags: seeds, citrus, germination, sprouting

I've [sprouted](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/9296/how-do-i-know-its-time-to-transfer-my-citrus-kumquat-to-a-bigger-flowerpot) two kumquat seeds from the same tree. One sprout looks very green and "healthy", with considerable [cotyledons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cotyledon), while the other is very pale, with tiny cotyledons, that aren't growing any more. What could be the reason for the difference? The soil and location are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if they're in the same pot or container - if not, then something about the other container and its soil isn't quite right, or the seedling itself is just weak. It happens...

Comment: They're not in the same pot. Is it better or worse to plant a few sprouts in the same pot?

Comment: Neither, really, not better or worse, but if you start them off together in a pot, you have to prick them out into separate pots once they get 2 sets of leaves, so they have enough room. Your other seedling is probably just a weak grower.